# How to fix overlapping issue

Tags: r

```
plot(USArrests$Murder, USArrests$UrbanPop, 
     xlab="murder", ylab="% urban population", pch=20, col="grey",
     ylim=c(20, 100), xlim=c(0, 20))
text(USArrests$Murder, USArrests$UrbanPop, labels=rownames(USArrests), 
     cex=0.7, pos=3)
```

[image]

I tried everything, reducing font size with cex, change the positions, change the ylim, xlim to fit the size, I also tried changing the margins, which didn't really help me so I got rid of them. At this point, I don't know how to do this with base R tool. I do know `ggplot` method, which is way easier. But I want to know if I can do the same task with the base `plot()`,`text()` code.

Comment: A very relevant answer was given by @MarcoSandri, unfortunately he took it down again. I second his recommendation to use `ggplot` together with `ggrepel`. As far as I am aware what you're asking for is difficult to achieve/automate in base R `plot`.

Answer (score 1):

To find neighbors which are *too* near you could run `kmeans()` cluster analysis about the data. It's quite a hack, though!

First, subset your data.

```
dat <- USArrests[c("Murder", "UrbanPop")]
```

Set a seed. Play around with that. Different seeds => different results.

```
set.seed(42)
```

Analyze clusters with `kmeans()`, option `centers` assigns number of clusters, play around with that.

```
dat$cl <- kmeans(dat, centers=10, nstart=5)$cluster
```

Now split data and assign altering `pos` numbers for positioning later in the `text()` command.

```
l <- split(dat, dat$cl)
l <- lapply(l, function(x) within(x, {
  if (nrow(x) == 1)
    pos <- 2  # for those with just one observation in cluster
  else
    pos <- as.numeric(as.character(factor((1:nrow(x)) %% 2, labels=c(2, 4))))
}))
```

Assemble.

```
dat <- do.call(rbind, unname(l))
```

Now plot into a `png` with a somewhat high resolution, I chose 800x800.

```
png("plot.png", 800, 800, "px")
plot(dat$Murder, dat$UrbanPop, xlab="murder", ylab="% urban population", 
     pch=20, col="grey",  ylim=c(20, 100), xlim=c(0, 20))
# the sapply assigns the text position according to `pos` column
sapply(c(4, 2), function(x) 
  with(dat[dat$pos == x, ], 
       text(Murder, UrbanPop, labels=rownames(dat[dat$pos == x, ]),
            cex=0.7, pos=x)))
dev.off()
```

***Which gives me:***

[image]

I'm sure you can optimize this further.